# Is there a way to Block abusive users

Tags: support, abuse

Is there a way to block an abusive user?

Answer (score 4):

#### Is there a way to block an abusive user?

If you come across a user who is abusive to you or others raise "rude or abusive" flag on one of their posts:

[image]

You can also raise "rude or abusive" flags on comments:

[image]

A moderator will then investigate and take appropriate action.